How to display a spatial image in SwiftUI
Does anyone have a suggestion on displaying a spatial image or video in SwiftUI on the Apple Vision Pro. When I use the standard Image view, the image looks flat. I have search for visionOS display spatial image and I am unable to find anything.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for responding, but that will only separate a 2D image from the background by lifting it. I'm looking for a way to display the image in the 3D format within the image, it's similar to looking into a 3d box instead of a lifted 2D picture. I hope my description makes sense.

Thank you for your suggestions, but those are different, I want to display exactly like in the photo's app for a spacial image already taken by Vision Pro. I'm really surprised that Apple doesn't provide a simple SwiftUI image control that detects their own image and displays it correctly. Seems like they are waiting for developers to provide the killer app and yet their SDK doesn't support its own content.

There is an example here: https://devcodef1.com/news/1228261/custom-spatial-image-views-in-swiftui
but the VisionProDisplay view does not resolve and I can't find any documentation on it.

[edit: added June 15, 2024]
There's sample code for spatial and image video display, and spatial image generation, in the WWDC 24 session Build compelling spatial photo and video experiences.

There's sample code for spatial video playback at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/destination-video, discussed during WWDC session 10070. AVPlayerViewController knows how to play back spatial video.
For spatial still photos, there's ShaderGraphMaterial, using Shader Graph Camera Index Switch node and a RealityView. In Reality Composer Pro, set up two Image File inputs feeding through the Camera Index Switch into an output material. I've used that approach to render stereo photographs as stereo. But you'll still have to figure out how to extract the left/right image pairs, or whatever the equivalent is, from the spatial photo.
This post looks promising, has some sample code (that I haven't tried myself) to extract left/right images: https://www.finnvoorhees.com/words/reading-and-writing-spatial-photos-with-image-io.
let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil)!
let leftImage: CGImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, nil)!
let rightImage: CGImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 1, nil)!


Thank you, much appreciated! This might be out of my league, but I'll give it my best.

Unfortunately, Apple's Demo doesn't work. It allows a 2D video to be displayed in an Immersive backdrop. Looks like Apple may have been correct that there is no way to display Spacial Video or Spacial images beyond 2D. If this is true, it's incredibly short sighted of Apple. I can display 3D models, but not Spacial media.

I tried your approach for spatial photos, the result looks a little paler/brighter than what it should be. Is there additional settings I need to tweak?

I've seen big variation in display quality between Simulator and Vision Pro with Xcode 15/visionOS 1.2. The display quality on Sim with Xcode 16/visionOS 2.0 is much improved, to my eye. If you are seeing discrepancies, post a new question with minimal repro, and sample images that demonstrate the problem.

VERY disappointing and frankly unbelievable, I sent Apple a support request to display their spacial image on their device using their SDK and this is the response:
Case-ID: 7126966
Hello James,
Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). We have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations.

You have to manually create a shader in Reality Composer Pro:

In the example above, the shader is named VRMaterial. There is no way to do this programmatically as of July 11th, 2024.
Then you need to retrieve that shader in your SwiftUI view, pass in a left and right image, and set the material to your ModelEntity:
// vrMaterial

let vrMaterial = try await ShaderGraphMaterial(
    named: "/VRMaterial",
    from: "Scene.usda",
    in: realityKitContentBundle
)

// textureResoure

let textureResoure = try await TextureResource.generate(
    from: (your cgImage)!,
    options: TextureResource.CreateOptions(
        semantic: .color
    )
)
            
// materialParameters

if textureResoure != nil {
    
    let materialParameters = MaterialParameters.Value.textureResource(
        textureResoure!
    )

    // set vrMaterial

    if materialParameters != nil {
        
        try vrMaterial?.setParameter(
            name: "LeftImageName",
            value: materialParameters!
        )
        
        try vrMaterial?.setParameter(
            name: "RightImageName",
            value: materialParameters!
        )
        
    }

    if vrMaterial != nil {
        
        print("sucess!")
        
        (your ModelEntity).model?.materials = [
            vrMaterial!
        ]
               
    }

}         

Unfortunately, you cannot test this on the simulator and need to purchase or borrow a physical Vision Pro.

You have to create a material in Reality Composer Pro with the following schematic

Then use it with a ShaderGraphMaterial with any Mesh to display it in a RealityView
let material = try await ShaderGraphMaterial(named: "/Root/ImageMaterial",
                                             from: "ImageMaterial",
                                             in: realityKitContentBundle)

entity.components.set(ModelComponent(mesh: /* ... */, materials: [material]))

Here are some very helpful links
How to make materials - https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10202
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc24/10104
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc24/10093
